# AWK, delete record when field match

Tags: bash, awk

I use a regular file that has 2 fields, 1st is account name (with spaces) and 2nd is an integer number, both fields separated with `\t` and all records are separated with `\n`. My problem is I need to delete records which match the 1st field string. My code below:

```
awk -v APENOM="$apeynom" -F "\t" ' $1 != APENOM { print $0; } ' $1 > $TEMP_FILE_2
```

It works for most records but not for the first record, it never matches first field from the first record?

Comment: You should post the input file *(or at least a sample)* and also the value of `$apeynom` and show the output you are currently getting and the output you expect.

Comment: Your input file was created on Windows and so has spurious control-Ms at the end of lines. Run `cat -v file` to see them and then run `dos2unix` on it and try again.

Comment: It whas notepad indeed, i realized that when i saw that particular character. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your script to:

```
'$1 != APENOM { print $0; next } { print "MISMATCH[", $1, "]" }'
```

I have a feeling that you have dirty input.  There might be a space before the separating tab character or something.  This will have it print out what `$1` is when you are skipping.

Comment: I realized that i was using a file created in notepad, edited in vi, but for something worng, first record never got deleted. I created it again, this time in vi and it suprisely worked! So problem was dirty input, it looks fine at vi, but it wasnt... i feel a dumbass, thanks for your help and time